# "não assistas TV" - correct?

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, modo-subjuntivo, imperfeito-ou-perfeito

Let's say, I want to say to my friend "don't watch TV", **with "tu"**. The imperative negative form of "assistir" is "(**tu**) não assistas". But when I search this very phrase in google, nothing appears, whereas for "(voce) não assista" some results do.

Why is that?
How to command to my friend "don't watch TV!"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, most Brazilians don’t use *tu*-conjugations, and tend to substitute the indicative for the imperative anyway. So you shouldn’t expect to hear *não assistas TV* from a Brazilian.

The Portuguese do use *tu*-conjugations, but they don’t say *assistir TV*; they say *ver TV* or, more commonly, *ver televisão*. So in Google you do find *não vejas TV* (16 results), ***não vejas televisão*** (156 results); *não veja tv* returns 1,280 results, most of them from Brazil, some from Portugal.

Comment: Indeed, most Brazilians don't use _tu_, and even in places where it is used, e.g. Rio Grande do Sul, Rio de Janeiro, it is used wrongly ("tu corre no campo" em vez de "tu corres no campo"). Moreover, in formal language, "assitir" without preposition means "to help", whereas "assistir a" means "to watch". Again, most Brazilians (and I speak as one) are oblivious to this fact.

Comment: @LoremIpsum, that's right. I wrote "*tu*-conjugations" rather than just *tu*  precisely exclude the *tu* +third person conjugations (I've recently seen a map of Brazil showing the distribution of *você*, *tu* +third person conjugation, *tu* +canonical conjugation, but can't find it now). There's a question here somewhere on the *assistir* vs *assistir a*. In Portugal we stick to that distinction, but we don't say *assistir a tv* either   (preposition *a* here), so I ignored the issue altogether. We may say *assisti a um debate na televisão*, or just *vi um debate*...